# Chrome not started with Python Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I got this error when running my code. BTW, I am running this behind a VPN.
Can anyone tell me how can I fix it?
BTW, I try --headless, but weird that only the default profile is started with headless.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> Chrome failed to start: exited normally.   (unknown error:
> DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
> chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has
> crashed.)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os    

os.environ['WDM_SSL_VERIFY'] = '0'
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "http://127.0.0.1:4780"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\nuc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") #e.g. C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 5') #e.g. Profile 3
# options.binary_location
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
driver.save_screenshot('ss.png')
```

Comment: Before executing the code, close all the chrome browser windows and try.

Comment: Well, I did close all Chrome windows, but no luck, still the same error.